# Fatal error: Class 'MongoDate' not found when using mongodb php driver 1.1.2 and PHP 7.0.2 - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to configure MongoDB to work with my Laravel 5.1 Homestead instance on a virtual Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I was able to successfully install the latest version of MongoDB which supports PHP 7.0 using `sudo pecl install mongodb` (this is correct for 7.0, *not* `sudo pecl install mongo` anymore).

I then added the extension in my php.ini files (all three) on my Ubuntu machine, each in:

- `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`
- `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`
- `/etc/php/7.0/cgi/php.ini`

This is the extension I wrote which is correct for use with PHP 7.0:

- `extension=mongodb.so` (not mongo.so anymore)

When I run `phpinfo()` in my browser, it states that MongoDB is properly configured with my PHP 7.0.

If MongoDB is properly configured, how come I keep getting:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoDate' not found
```

when I try to run my migrations and seeds with `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`?

I already tried:

- rebooting the Ubuntu machine with `vagrant reload` and `vagrant reload --provision`
- Restarting PHP and Nginx with `sudo service nginx restart` and `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

Neither have worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you mentioned you're using the new Mongo extension for PHP 7.

The class names have changed from the older version, i.e.

`MongoClient` is now `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`

`MongoDate` is now `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime`

I'm not sure how backwards compatible everything is, but this should get you started!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and see if it works for my use case.

Comment: You should probably use the mongo PHP library as well which has some higher level APIs which are more convenient than using the driver directly... https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

Comment: I've found that MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime expects input in milliseconds (vs MongoDate which seemed to take seconds). I'm now using this helper class to workaround the issue when passing unix timestamps into both functions: https://gist.github.com/jonmilsom/75e871c513604d1193a1

Answer (score 4):

Throughout our app we were regularly converting unix timestamps into MongoDate instances. Example:

```
new MongoDate(strtotime('-1 day'));
```

I've therefore created a class to allow conversion between unix timestamps and the new `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime`, and back

```
<?php

class MongoHelper {

    const SECONDS_IN_A_MILLISECOND = 1000;

    public static function getMongoUTCDateTimeFromUnixTimestamp($timestamp) {
        return new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(intval($timestamp * self::SECONDS_IN_A_MILLISECOND));
    }

    public static function getUnixTimestampFromMongoUTCDateTime(\MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime $utc_date_time) {
        return intval((string) $utc_date_time / self::SECONDS_IN_A_MILLISECOND);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
MongoHelper::getMongoUTCDateTimeFromUnixTimestamp(strtotime('-1 day'));
```